# How do I fix php code not executing with input from a form?

Tags: php, forms, file, ssh

I am new here and to php.

I am running a simple php code to ssh into a remote server and execute a long command:

```
ldapsearch -b o=Devices -h 24.33.42.43 -D "uid=aaa_user,ou=AppUsers,o=services" -w "authAuthAcc01" rrWiFiDeviceMAC="A4-F1-E8-24-6B-28"
```

for a specific MAC Address **A4-F1-E8-24-6B-28**. I used a form to input a MAC Address, then submit to execute ssh into the linux server before executing the command above. `echo $CMD` will display the full command on the page indicating `$var=$_POST[]` works. However, the code won't run to ssh2 function. It's like `$var` becomes empty or something. But if I hardcode `$var` and run from PHP command line it works.
 Please, what am I doing wrong!

Thanks for your help.

```
<form  action="MAC_search.php" method="post">
    Enter MAC Address to Search:<input type="text" name="mac">
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value ='Search' />
</form>



<?php
   if ($_POST["submit"] ){
   $MACD=$_POST['mac'];
   //$MACD='F8-62-14-E9-F7-51';  *****Hardcoding here works*****
    $CMD = "ldapsearch -b o=Devices -h 24.33.33.5 -D \"uid=a . 
    aa_user,ou=AppUsers,o=services\" -w \"authAuthAcc01\" 
    rrWiFiDeviceMAC=\"$MACD\"";

    echo $CMD; **** Here echos on the page also *******
    $connection = ssh2_connect("x.x.x.x", 22);        
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "$CMD");
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);

   $resultfile = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("unable to open 
    file");  
    fwrite($resultfile, $output);
    fclose($myfile);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please print error ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Did you install ssh2 extension in php? Please check in phpinfo() 
http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: I did install ssh2, unfortunately, for some reason it did not take effect. So after restarting httpd it started working. Thanks alot!